# Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor' not found

Tags: php, magento2.2

we are having problem with accessing backend login into magento 2.2.4 site. Everything else on the frond-end seems to work.

INFO:

PHP version: 7.1.33

Magento version: 2.2.4

ERORR:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor' not found in /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Backend...', Array) #1 /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Backend...') #2 /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Backend...') #3 /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Backend...') #4 /home/rrkv11/domains/bud in /home/rrkv11/domains/site-name/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working...
The interceptor file needed to be re-created with simple commands:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php  bin/magento  cache:clean